# Java CookSwing - handling special characters like ä,ö,ü

Tags: java, xml, user-interface

i need to use [CookSwing](http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswing/). I generate the XMLs out of information of a content management system.

If I use any character like ä,ö,ü or ß in these xmls, cookswing doesn't do anything. No exceptions, no rendering of the xml.

How can I handle these characters without replacing them?

Comment: In principle, Java has no problems with this ... it could be a problem in CookSwing. (I think at least the not-throwing of exceptions is, even if your XML is wrong.)

Comment: Just for debugging: Does it work if you use &#0xE4; and similar?

Comment: Other than this: Could you show the Java code you are using to create the GUI, and could you a sample XML?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the proper encoding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```